# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘glmmTMB’

Tags: rcpp, glmmtmb, tmb

I am trying to use package glmmTMB. When I call library(glmmTMB) this is the error message:

> ">library(glmmTMB)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘glmmTMB’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
> function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: package ‘glmmTMB’ was built under R version 4.0.5
> 2: In checkMatrixPackageVersion() :
> Package version inconsistency detected.
> TMB was built with Matrix version 1.3.4
> Current Matrix version is 1.2.18
> Please re-install 'TMB' from source using install.packages('TMB', type = 'source') or ask CRAN for a binary version of 'TMB' matching CRAN's 'Matrix' package

I have tried using install.packages('TMB', type = 'source') with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's a FAQ -- search for `'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'`.

In short you are mixing a NEWER compilatio nof something that was built with Rcpp 1.0.7 present with an older installed version which lacks the symbol.

Fix: `install.packages("Rcpp")` to get the newer `Rcpp`.  And I generally recommend regular `update.packages()` runs to avoid these issues.

Comment: I fixed the Rcpp issue via an update - thank you! However the TMB error remains 

Please re-install 'TMB' from source using install.packages('TMB', type = 'source') or ask CRAN for a binary version of 'TMB' matching CRAN's 'Matrix' package

I have successfully uninstalled and reinstalled this package using remove.packages("TMB"), and install.packages('TMB', type = 'source')